# Enabling completion with tab on an old ksh on SystemV

Tags: ksh, system-v

Is it possible to make completion with <kbd>Tab</kbd> like in bash?

Currently I use <kbd>Esc</kbd> twice, can this be changed to a tab?

Comment: Holy moly, you're using a System V machine?

Comment: Only for test study,i like old system like dos,unix sysV,even unix v7(1979),for work and at home i use linux,hpux,aix and sometimes ios

Comment: It does not appear that [ksh88](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh88.html) implements configurable key bindings

Comment: I have configured alias for use arrow keys instead ctrl+p,ctrl+n,etc i though was possible alias esc too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is solved: with ksh93 is possible to change completion key, but with ksh88 it's not possible

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure *which* version of System V you're using, nor which version of `ksh`, but it's possible to change the completion key to <kbd>Tab</kbd> with ksh93 (not with ksh88, though, I believe).

Depending on age, these in your `~/.profile` *may* do it:

```
set -o emacs
bind bind "^I=complete"
```

See [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83695/5186) for more info.

Comment: sure work,but on my unix srv4(att 2.1) ksh is ksh88,anyway thanks