# Auto-Complete the path on AIX using profile

Tags: autocomplete, aix

We have an AIX environment in which I have to use <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> to complete the path. In a RHEL environment I was able complete the path using <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Is it possible to get this <kbd>Tab</kbd> auto complete feature going in AIX environment too?

Comment: Related: [Can ksh on AIX be configured to use the tab key for filename completion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83695/can-ksh-on-aix-be-configured-to-use-the-tab-key-for-filename-completion)

Comment: This is a feature of the shell.  Are you using `ksh88` or `ksh93`? Are you using `vi` or `emacs` command line editing mode?

Comment: we use vi editor and ksh93 shell.

Answer (score 0):

AIX use ksh(korn shell) Redhat use Bash(bourne again shell)
So solution is simple.
Install bash on aix.
Here is the [repo](http://www.perzl.org/aix/),and you can use also yum.
Then with chuser command change shell of user.

Comment: Installing binaries is not an option. Because am just an user of the server and only an SA can do such binary installs on the server.

Comment: Ok,so is (at least as I know) impossible to use tab instead of esc.Tab is used for BASH completion,non for KSH completion,there are two different shells,even if similar in some parts. Ask for install bash to sysadmin,or use ESC,I cannot see other solution.